# JsonPropertyNameAttribute is not supported record from C#9?

Tags: c#, .net-5, system.text.json, c#-9.0

I want to use record with JsonPropertyName attribute, but it caused an error. This is not supported? Any workaround?

```
public record QuoteResponse([JsonPropertyName("quotes")] IReadOnlyCollection<Quote>? Quotes);

Error CS0592 Attribute 'JsonPropertyName' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer, field' declarations.
```

[image]

Comment: Closely related question [How do I target attributes for a record class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63778276/how-do-i-target-attributes-for-a-record-class)

Answer (score 47):

By default attributes on record parameters apply to the parameter. To make them apply to the property you have to prefix it with the `property:` attribute location:

```cs
public record QuoteResponse([property: JsonPropertyName("quotes")] IReadOnlyCollection<Quote>? Quotes);
```

Comment: didn't know we could do that.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 ways (that I know of) to create a record, the below will  hopefully solve it for you.

```
public record QuoteResponse
{
    [JsonPropertyName("quotes")]
    public IReadOnlyCollection<Quote>? Quotes {get; init;}
}
```

Comment: Without a Set or Init modifier, the property will not be initialized. Then how will it differ from the class?

Comment: Thanks for noticing it should have an init after the get. I will update my code now.