# Data Annotations on record fails in unittest

Tags: c#, record, xunit, .net-5, c#-9.0

Currently we are setting up a new project and like to use the new records introduced in C# 9.
We encounter a problem with DataAnnotations inside the record (constructor) not being triggered during the unittest.

Now the DataAnnotation is triggered when calling the Controller, but when i try to simulate this in a unittest (see code below) it will never return any errors.

```
        //Unit Testing ASP.NET DataAnnotations validation
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167811/unit-testing-asp-net-dataannotations-validation
        protected static IList<ValidationResult> ValidateModel(object model)
        {
            var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var ctx = new ValidationContext(model, null, null);
            Validator.TryValidateObject(model, ctx, validationResults, true);
            return validationResults;
        }
```

Currently we created a workaround:

```
    public record FooRecord(string BarProperty)
    {
        [Required]
        public string BarProperty { get; init; } = BarProperty;

    }
```

But I'm hoping if someone knows why this happens and maybe know how to solve this using the shorthand syntax:

```
    public record FooRecord([Required] BarProperty){ }
```

Answer (score 5):

It will work as expected if you define your record as:

```
public record FooRecord([property: Required] BarProperty){ }
```

Comment: I have `[StringLength]` attribute. I expect it should work same way.

`property: ` gives the following error:
`Record type 'AuthCodeRequest' has validation metadata defined on property 'AuthCode' that will be ignored. 'AuthCode' is a parameter in the record primary constructor and validation metadata must be associated with the constructor parameter`

`param: ` and just `[StringLength]` works

Comment: Also worked for MongoDb driver such as [property: Bson]

Comment: same error as SerjG

Answer (score 0):

### Behavior of ASP.NET Core request parameters

You can't apply validation attributes `[property: ... ]` to your request parameters that undergoes binding & validation, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65934513/net-5-0-web-api-wont-work-with-record-featuring-required-properties).

You will receive `InvalidOperationException(...)` like @SerjG describes in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66238214/data-annotations-on-record-fails-in-unittest#comment126109692_67268499).

It happend to me too and that is the reason why end up in this SO thread.

For details, see [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24265).

### Solution

- Replace remove your validation attributes.
- Use Fluent Validation instead.