# `[Required]` DataAnnotation not validating DTO

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

I have DTOs as such to create user

```
public record IWriteDTO();
public record CreateUserDTO(string FirstName, string LastName, [Required] string UserName,
                            [Required] string Email, List<CreateSkillDTO> Skills) : IWriteDTO;
```

Both Email and UserName fields are decorated with `[Required]` attribute from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` however when I use the swagger endpoint with empty `UserName` and `Email` values controller does not respond back with an invalid request etc.

I send requests with the body like below:

```
{
  "firstName": "string",
  "lastName": "string",
  //no UserName
  //no email
  "skills": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "description": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Controller to Create Users

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserDTO>> CreateUserAsync(CreateUserDTO user)
{
            
   var createdUser = await _userService.CreateAsync(user);

   return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetUserAsync), new { id = createdUser.Id }, createdUser);
}
```

My controller returns 201 with the created `UserDTO` however returned UserDTO has `UserName: null` and `Email: null` which is really not a wanted behaviour

```
{
  "id": "aef16a1d-3573-4676-9d9f-14ed26ac669a",
  "firstName": "string",
  "lastName": "string",
  "fullName": "string string",
  "userName": null,
  "email": null,
  "skills": [
    {
      "id": "42c416a1-4203-406e-acba-8d35f2e73840",
      "name": "string",
      "description": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Before someone suggests it I know I can write fluent validations however I want to fix this issue and keep it simple since currently, I am working on an MVP.

Many Thanks to anyone who takes their time to help

**Edit**
according to blog post [here](https://www.daveabrock.com/2020/11/18/simplify-api-models-with-records/) .NET 5 supports such syntax

**Solution**
While looking I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65934513/net-5-0-web-api-wont-work-with-record-featuring-required-properties) with suggestions as links checking [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63778276/how-do-i-target-attributes-for-a-record-class) I targeted the property and it worked

```
public record IWriteDTO();
public record CreateUserDTO(string FirstName, string LastName, 
                           [property : Required] string UserName, 
                           [property : Required] string Email,  
                           List<CreateSkillDTO> Skills) : IWriteDTO;
```

It may be a bug regarding using Annotations on records however solved my problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

The model parser will use the attributes you specified while filling the method parameters from the incoming request. But you still have to ask it how everything went, like this:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return BadRequest();
}

// model is valid, proceed
```

Instead of just replying with `BadRequest()` you can also construcct a more detailed response, the [ModelState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelstatedictionary?view=aspnetcore-5.0) object has properties to help you with that.

For more info, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation).

Comment: I added your snippet to my controller however ModelState.IsValid returns true even when I don't include required elements. Also [in this tutorial](https://youtu.be/ZXdFisA_hOY?t=4062) I followed he only adds the `[required]` attribute, at the given timestamp record syntax is different however he changes them later to the syntax I use